# Is it possible to turn on Samsung smart TV, Tizen OS through network?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

My TV model is UA43J5500AJXZK
Is it possible to control, generally Tizen OS, on/off, switch input channel, through network or wireless?
The old way does not work anymore, by sending tcp packet directly, as the port has been removed.

Comment: [This](http://www.iguanaworks.net/products/usb-ir-transceiver/) and [that](http://www.lirc.org/). Besides, voting to close as your question is way too broad.

Comment: At SDC 2016 in San Francisco someone from the Samsung Visual Display Group (TV division) mentioned a Tizen TV OS update later this year (2016), which should open CEC (Consumer Electronics Control) over HDMI allowing external devices to turn on the TV by sending a command. Don't know what the status of that update is, and if your specific TV will receive that update.